# Extended-Chacha20

Tags: stream-cipher, chacha

Research paper: "[Extended-Chacha20 Stream Cipher With
Enhanced Quarter Round Function](https://bth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1810206/FULLTEXT01.pdf)"

1. The initial matrix is 6x6, but what are the exact inputs for each index, in other words, how will you fill the two additional columns that are added to the matrix?
2. Is it possible to change the constant values? and is it based on a specific theory?
3. Is it possible to have 3 or 4 procedures of rotation instead of 2 (columns and rows) for 36 rounds?
4. Can I change the order of the words in the matrix?

Comment: I have only glanced at the paper, but I can't take it seriously when it claims to have a larger key and nonce size than ChaCha20 when it's identical to the original/Bernstein ChaCha20 and has a smaller nonce size than the IETF/standardised ChaCha20. It also makes other erroneous claims like ChaCha20 being universally more efficient than AES. Adding more rounds for security is overkill when the security margin is currently ~13 rounds. Then the paper hasn't referenced [Forro](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-023-09455-5) and cites a flawed security analysis of ChaCha20-Poly1305.